# I had a problem when overloading the operator ">>" and i don't have any idea what is going on

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have read other responses to similar problems but nothing has worked. Those responses suggest including `#include <string>`, but that didn't work. Also, I tried making the overloads `friend` functions in the `User` class, but that didn't work.

This is the `User` class:

```cpp
class User
{
    bool status;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    public:
        static int user_count;
        User()
        {
            status = 0;
            first_name = "first";
            last_name = "last";
            user_count++;
        }
        User(std::string new_first, std::string new_last, bool new_status)
        {
            first_name = new_first;
            last_name = new_last;
            status = new_status;
            user_count++;
        }
        //Some getters and setters...
        ~User()
        {
            user_count--;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, User&);
        friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream&, User&);
};
```

And yes, I initialized the `user_count` outside of the class.

These are the overloads:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& output, User& user)
{
    output << "First name: " << user.first_name << "\nLast name: " << user.last_name;
    return output;
}

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& input, User& user)
{
    input >> user.first_name >> user.last_name >> user.status;
    return input;
}
```

This is the `main()` function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    User user();

    std::cin >> user;

    std::cout << user << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The headers are:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

**EDIT**: I did not explain myself very well. I was following a tutorial on YouTube about operator overloading, and I was copying exactly what the guy in the video was doing, the overload on `<<` was working fine, but when trying to do so on `>>` I got this huge error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:75:14: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream’ {aka ‘std::basic_istream<char>’} and ‘User(’)
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |     ~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~
      |          |      |
      |          |      User()
      |          std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:120:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  120 |       operator>>(__istream_type& (*__pf)(__istream_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:120:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_istream<char>& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>&)’} [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:124:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]’ <near match>
  124 |       operator>>(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:124:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)’} [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:131:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  131 |       operator>>(ios_base& (*__pf)(ios_base&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:131:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:168:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  168 |       operator>>(bool& __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:168:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘bool&’ to an rvalue of type ‘bool’
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:172:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ <near match>
  172 |       operator>>(short& __n);
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:172:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘short int’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(short int)user’ to ‘short int&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:175:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  175 |       operator>>(unsigned short& __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:175:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘short unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(short unsigned int)user’ to ‘short unsigned int&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:179:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ <near match>
  179 |       operator>>(int& __n);
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:179:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(int)user’ to ‘int&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:182:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  182 |       operator>>(unsigned int& __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:182:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(unsigned int)user’ to ‘unsigned int&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:186:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  186 |       operator>>(long& __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:186:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘long int’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(long int)user’ to ‘long int&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:190:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  190 |       operator>>(unsigned long& __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:190:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘long unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(long unsigned int)user’ to ‘long unsigned int&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:195:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  195 |       operator>>(long long& __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:195:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘long long int’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(long long int)user’ to ‘long long int&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:199:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  199 |       operator>>(unsigned long long& __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:199:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘long long unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(long long unsigned int)user’ to ‘long long unsigned int&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:235:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(void*&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’ <near match>
  235 |       operator>>(void*& __p)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:235:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:75:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘User (*)()’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
      |                 |
      |                 User (*)()
main.cpp:75:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(void*)user’ to ‘void*&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:214:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(float&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’
  214 |       operator>>(float& __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:214:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘User()’ to ‘float&’
  214 |       operator>>(float& __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:218:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(double&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’
  218 |       operator>>(double& __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:218:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘User()’ to ‘double&’
  218 |       operator>>(double& __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:222:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long double&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]’
  222 |       operator>>(long double& __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:222:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘User()’ to ‘long double&’
  222 |       operator>>(long double& __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:259:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]’
  259 |       operator>>(__streambuf_type* __sb);
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:259:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘User()’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::__streambuf_type*’ {aka ‘std::basic_streambuf<char>*’}
  259 |       operator>>(__streambuf_type* __sb);
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
main.cpp:65:15: note: candidate: ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, User&)’
   65 | std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& input, User& user)
      |               ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:65:54: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘User()’ to ‘User&’
   65 | std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& input, User& user)
      |                                                ~~~~~~^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:56,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.tcc:1466:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)’
 1466 |     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.tcc:1466:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:75:17: note:   mismatched types ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘User()’
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:991,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/istream.tcc:931:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)’
  931 |     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT& __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/istream.tcc:931:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:75:17: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT’ (‘char’ and ‘User()’)
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:756:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)’
  756 |     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char& __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:756:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:75:17: note:   cannot convert ‘user’ (type ‘User()’) to type ‘unsigned char&’
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:761:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)’
  761 |     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char& __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:761:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:75:17: note:   cannot convert ‘user’ (type ‘User()’) to type ‘signed char&’
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:991,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/istream.tcc:963:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)’
  963 |     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/istream.tcc:963:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:75:17: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT2’ (‘char’ and ‘User()’)
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:803:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)’
  803 |     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:803:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:75:17: note:   cannot convert ‘user’ (type ‘User()’) to type ‘unsigned char*’
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:808:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)’
  808 |     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:808:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:75:17: note:   cannot convert ‘user’ (type ‘User()’) to type ‘signed char*’
   75 |     std::cin >> user;
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:40,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:980:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Istream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Istream>, std::__is_extractable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type, _Tp&&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type>::type std::operator>>(_Istream&&, _Tp&&)’
  980 |     operator>>(_Istream&& __is, _Tp&& __x)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:980:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9/istream: In substitution of ‘template<class _Istream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Istream>, std::__is_extractable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type, _Tp&&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type>::type std::operator>>(_Istream&&, _Tp&&) [with _Istream = std::basic_istream<char>&; _Tp = User (&)()]’:
main.cpp:75:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/istream:980:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_istream<char>&>’
```

Hope it helps a little bit more.

Comment: What specific issue are you running into? Can you show us the input to the program you’re giving and the output that isn’t correct?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As stated above, please provide the exact problem you have with your source code. Currently we can only guess, what's going wrong.

Comment: The only thing that the vscode tell me is that "no operator '>>' matches these operands -- operand types are: std::istream >> User ()". I was following a tutorial on youtube on the subject (operator overload), the "<<" worked fine but i got the above error when overloading ">>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `main()`, `User user();` declares a **function** named `user` that takes no arguments and returns a `User`. That is not what you want in this situation.  You want an **object instance** instead.  So, you need to drop the parenthesis from the declaration, eg: `User user;` That declares a **variable** named `user` of type `User` and then calls its default constructor.

Also, in `operator<<`, the 2nd parameter should be declared as `const User& user` instead.

Comment: Holy sh*t, that actually worked, but why? The default constructor is overriden by the one i defined without arguments?

Comment: Like I said, `User user()` defines a *function*, not an *object*. You can't pass a function to `operator>>` or `operator<<` (well, not the kind of function you are defining, anyway). You don't want a function in this situation, you want an object instead.